core.default_timezone airflow for CDT
How to assign the time zone for Us -central CDT in airflow { like core.default_timezone = utc }
I am trying to find out the similar one for central for Utc . I tried us/cdt ,us/cst

You might use US/Central, it is backward to America/Chicago (according to the list into the Wikipedia) and depend of datetime it would be Central Standard Time (CST) or Central Daylight Time (CDT)
